# Como logro recorrer este json con for anidado los arrays y objetos que estan dentro de otros arrays y objetos

Tags: javascript

```javascript
const data = [{
    "num": "001",
    "name": "bulbasaur",
    "generation": {
        "num": "generation i",
        "name": "kanto"},
    "about": "Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight. There is a seed on its back. By soaking up the sun's rays, the seed grows progressively larger.",
    "img": "https://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
    "size": {
        "height": "0.71 m",
        "weight": "6.9 kg"},
    "pokemon-rarity": "normal",
    "type": [
        "grass",
        "poison"],
    "encounter": {
        "base-flee-rate": "0.1",
        "base-capture-rate": "0.2"},
    "spawn-chance": "0.69",
    "stats": {
        "base-attack": "118",
        "base-defense": "111",
        "base-stamina": "128",
        "max-cp": "1115",
        "max-hp": "113"},
    "resistant": [
        "water",
        "electric",
        "grass",
        "fighting",
        "fairy"],
    "weaknesses": [
        "fire",
        "ice",
        "flying",
        "psychic"],
    "quick-move": [{
            "name": "vine whip",
            "type": "grass",
            "base-damage": "7",
            "energy": "6",
            "move-duration-seg": "0.6"},
        {
            "name": "tackle",
            "type": "normal",
            "base-damage": "5",
            "energy": "5",
            "move-duration-seg": "0.5"}],
    "special-attack": [
        {
            "name": "sludge bomb",
            "type": "poison",
            "base-damage": "80",
            "energy": "-50",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.3"
        },
        {
            "name": "seed bomb",
            "type": "grass",
            "base-damage": "55",
            "energy": "-33",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.1"
        },
        {
            "name": "power whip",
            "type": "grass",
            "base-damage": "90",
            "energy": "-50",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.6"
        }
    ],
    "egg": "2 km",
    "buddy-distance-km": "3",
    "evolution": {
        "candy": "bulbasaur candy",
        "next-evolution": [{
            "num": "002",
            "name": "ivysaur",
            "candy-cost": "25",
            "next-evolution": [{
                "num": "003",
                "name": "venusaur",
                "candy-cost": "100"
            }]
        }]
    }
},
{
    "num": "002",
    "name": "ivysaur",
    "generation": {
        "num": "generation i",
        "name": "kanto"
    },
    "about": "There is a bud on this Pokémon's back. To support its weight, Ivysaur's legs and trunk grow thick and strong. If it starts spending more time lying in the sunlight, it's a sign that the bud will bloom into a large flower soon.",
    "img": "https://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/002.png",
    "size": {
        "height": "0.99 m",
        "weight": "13.0 kg"
    },
    "pokemon-rarity": "normal",
    "type": [
        "grass",
        "poison"
    ],
    "encounter": {
        "base-flee-rate": "0.07",
        "base-capture-rate": "0.1"
    },
    "spawn-chance": "0.042",
    "stats": {
        "base-attack": "151",
        "base-defense": "143",
        "base-stamina": "155",
        "max-cp": "1699",
        "max-hp": "134"
    },
    "resistant": [
        "water",
        "electric",
        "grass",
        "fighting",
        "fairy"
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
        "fire",
        "ice",
        "flying",
        "psychic"
    ],
    "quick-move": [
        {
            "name": "razor leaf",
            "type": "grass",
            "base-damage": "13",
            "energy": "7",
            "move-duration-seg": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "vine whip",
            "type": "grass",
            "base-damage": "7",
            "energy": "6",
            "move-duration-seg": "0.6"
        }
    ],
    "special-attack": [
        {
            "name": "sludge bomb",
            "type": "poison",
            "base-damage": "80",
            "energy": "-50",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.3"
        },
        {
            "name": "solar beam",
            "type": "grass",
            "base-damage": "180",
            "energy": "-100",
            "move-duration-seg": "4.9"
        },
        {
            "name": "power whip",
            "type": "grass",
            "base-damage": "90",
            "energy": "-50",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.6"
        }
    ],
    "egg": "not in eggs",
    "buddy-distance-km": "3",
    "evolution": {
        "candy": "bulbasaur candy",
        "next-evolution": [{
            "num": "003",
            "name": "venusaur",
            "candy-cost": "100"
        }],
        "prev-evolution": [{
            "num": "001",
            "name": "bulbasaur",
            "candy-cost": "25"
        }]
    }
},
{
    "num": "003",
    "name": "venusaur",
    "generation": {
        "num": "generation i",
        "name": "kanto"
    },
    "about": "There is a large flower on Venusaur's back. The flower is said to take on vivid colors if it gets plenty of nutrition and sunlight. The flower's aroma soothes the emotions of people.",
    "img": "https://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/003.png",
    "size": {
        "height": "2.01 m",
        "weight": "100.0 kg"
    },
    "pokemon-rarity": "normal",
    "type": [
        "grass",
        "poison"
    ],
    "encounter": {
        "base-flee-rate": "0.05",
        "base-capture-rate": "0.05"
    },
    "spawn-chance": "0.017",
    "stats": {
        "base-attack": "198",
        "base-defense": "189",
        "base-stamina": "190",
        "max-cp": "2720",
        "max-hp": "162"
    },
    "resistant": [
        "water",
        "electric",
        "grass",
        "fighting",
        "fairy"
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
        "fire",
        "ice",
        "flying",
        "psychic"
    ],
    "quick-move": [
        {
            "name": "razor leaf",
            "type": "grass",
            "base-damage": "13",
            "energy": "7",
            "move-duration-seg": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "vine whip",
            "type": "grass",
            "base-damage": "7",
            "energy": "6",
            "move-duration-seg": "0.6"
        }
    ],
    "special-attack": [
        {
            "name": "sludge bomb",
            "type": "poison",
            "base-damage": "80",
            "energy": "-50",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.3"
        },
        {
            "name": "petal blizzard",
            "type": "grass",
            "base-damage": "110",
            "energy": "-100",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.6"
        },
        {
            "name": "solar beam",
            "type": "grass",
            "base-damage": "180",
            "energy": "-100",
            "move-duration-seg": "4.9"
        }
    ],
    "egg": "not in eggs",
    "buddy-distance-km": "3",
    "evolution": {
        "candy": "bulbasaur candy",
        "prev-evolution": [{
            "num": "002",
            "name": "ivysaur",
            "candy-cost": "100",
            "prev-evolution": [{
                "num": "001",
                "name": "bulbasaur",
                "candy-cost": "25"
            }]
        }]
    }
},
{
    "num": "004",
    "name": "charmander",
    "generation": {
        "num": "generation i",
        "name": "kanto"
    },
    "about": "The flame that burns at the tip of its tail is an indication of its emotions. The flame wavers when Charmander is enjoying itself. If the Pokémon becomes enraged, the flame burns fiercely.",
    "img": "https://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/004.png",
    "size": {
        "height": "0.61 m",
        "weight": "8.5 kg"
    },
    "pokemon-rarity": "normal",
    "type": [
        "fire"
    ],
    "encounter": {
        "base-flee-rate": "0.1",
        "base-capture-rate": "0.2"
    },
    "spawn-chance": "0.253",
    "stats": {
        "base-attack": "116",
        "base-defense": "93",
        "base-stamina": "118",
        "max-cp": "980",
        "max-hp": "105"
    },
    "resistant": [
        "fire",
        "grass",
        "ice",
        "bug",
        "steel"
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
        "water",
        "ground",
        "rock"
    ],
    "quick-move": [
        {
            "name": "ember",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "10",
            "energy": "10",
            "move-duration-seg": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "scratch",
            "type": "normal",
            "base-damage": "6",
            "energy": "4",
            "move-duration-seg": "0.5"
        }
    ],
    "special-attack": [
        {
            "name": "flame charge",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "70",
            "energy": "-33",
            "move-duration-seg": "3.8"
        },
        {
            "name": "flame burst",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "70",
            "energy": "-50",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.6"
        },
        {
            "name": "flamethrower",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "70",
            "energy": "-50",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.2"
        }
    ],
    "egg": "2 km",
    "buddy-distance-km": "3",
    "evolution": {
        "candy": "charmander candy",
        "next-evolution": [{
            "num": "005",
            "name": "charmeleon",
            "candy-cost": "25",
            "next-evolution": [{
                "num": "006",
                "name": "charizard",
                "candy-cost": "100"
            }]
        }]
    }
},
{
    "num": "005",
    "name": "charmeleon",
    "generation": {
        "num": "generation i",
        "name": "kanto"
    },
    "about": "Charmeleon mercilessly destroys its foes using its sharp claws. If it encounters a strong foe, it turns aggressive. In this excited state, the flame at the tip of its tail flares with a bluish white color.",
    "img": "https://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/005.png",
    "size": {
        "height": "1.09 m",
        "weight": "19.0 kg"
    },
    "pokemon-rarity": "normal",
    "type": [
        "fire"
    ],
    "encounter": {
        "base-flee-rate": "0.07",
        "base-capture-rate": "0.1"
    },
    "spawn-chance": "0.012",
    "stats": {
        "base-attack": "158",
        "base-defense": "126",
        "base-stamina": "151",
        "max-cp": "1653",
        "max-hp": "131"
    },
    "resistant": [
        "fire",
        "grass",
        "ice",
        "bug",
        "steel"
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
        "water",
        "ground",
        "rock"
    ],
    "quick-move": [
        {
            "name": "ember",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "10",
            "energy": "10",
            "move-duration-seg": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "fire fang",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "11",
            "energy": "8",
            "move-duration-seg": "0.9"
        },
        {
            "name": "scratch",
            "type": "normal",
            "base-damage": "6",
            "energy": "4",
            "move-duration-seg": "0.5"
        }
    ],
    "special-attack": [
        {
            "name": "fire punch",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "55",
            "energy": "-33",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "flame burst",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "70",
            "energy": "-50",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.6"
        },
        {
            "name": "flamethrower",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "70",
            "energy": "-50",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.2"
        }
    ],
    "egg": "not in eggs",
    "buddy-distance-km": "3",
    "evolution": {
        "candy": "charmander candy",
        "next-evolution": [{
            "num": "006",
            "name": "charizard",
            "candy-cost": "100"
        }],
        "prev-evolution": [{
            "num": "004",
            "name": "charmander",
            "candy-cost": "25"
        }]
    }
},
{
    "num": "006",
    "name": "charizard",
    "generation": {
        "num": "generation i",
        "name": "kanto"
    },
    "about": "Charizard flies around the sky in search of powerful opponents. It breathes fire of such great heat that it melts anything. However, it never turns its fiery breath on any opponent weaker than itself.",
    "img": "https://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/006.png",
    "size": {
        "height": "1.70 m",
        "weight": "90.5 kg"
    },
    "pokemon-rarity": "normal",
    "type": [
        "fire",
        "flying"
    ],
    "encounter": {
        "base-flee-rate": "0.05",
        "base-capture-rate": "0.05"
    },
    "spawn-chance": "0.0031",
    "stats": {
        "base-attack": "223",
        "base-defense": "173",
        "base-stamina": "186",
        "max-cp": "2889",
        "max-hp": "158"
    },
    "resistant": [
        "fire",
        "grass",
        "fighting",
        "bug",
        "steel"
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
        "water",
        "electric",
        "rock"
    ],
    "quick-move": [
        {
            "name": "fire spin",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "14",
            "energy": "10",
            "move-duration-seg": "1.1"
        },
        {
            "name": "air slash",
            "type": "flying",
            "base-damage": "14",
            "energy": "10",
            "move-duration-seg": "1.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "ember",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "10",
            "energy": "10",
            "move-duration-seg": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "wing attack",
            "type": "flying",
            "base-damage": "8",
            "energy": "9",
            "move-duration-seg": "0.8"
        }
    ],
    "special-attack": [
        {
            "name": "fire blast",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "140",
            "energy": "-100",
            "move-duration-seg": "4.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "dragon claw",
            "type": "dragon",
            "base-damage": "50",
            "energy": "-33",
            "move-duration-seg": "1.7"
        },
        {
            "name": "overheat",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "160",
            "energy": "-100",
            "move-duration-seg": "4"
        },
        {
            "name": "flamethrower",
            "type": "fire",
            "base-damage": "70",
            "energy": "-50",
            "move-duration-seg": "2.2"
        }
    ],
    "egg": "not in eggs",
    "buddy-distance-km": "3",
    "evolution": {
        "candy": "charmander candy",
        "prev-evolution": [{
            "num": "005",
            "name": "charmeleon",
            "candy-cost": "100",
            "prev-evolution": [{
                "num": "004",
                "name": "charmander",
                "candy-cost": "25"
            }]
        }]
    }
}]
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Para recorrer el JSON con estructuras anidadas, puedes utilizar bucles for anidados.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo recorrer el JSON que proporcionaste:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "num": "001",
    "name": "bulbasaur",
    "generation": {
      "num": "generation i",
      "name": "kanto"
    },
    "about": "Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight. There is a seed on its back. By soaking up the sun's rays, the seed grows progressively larger.",
    "img": "https://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
    "size": {
      "height": "0.71 m",
      "weight": "6.9 kg"
    },
    "pokemon-rarity": "normal",
    "type": [
      "grass",
      "poison"
    ],
    "encounter": {
      "base-flee-rate": "0.1",
      "base-capture-rate": "0.2"
    },
    "spawn-chance": "0.69",
    "stats": {
      "base-attack": "118",
      "base-defense": "111",
      "base-stamina": "128",
      "max-cp": "1115",
      "max-hp": "113"
    },
    "resistant": [
      "water",
      "electric",
      "grass",
      "fighting",
      "fairy"
    ],
    "weaknesses": [
      "fire",
      "ice",
      "flying",
      "psychic"
    ],
    "quick-move": [
      {
        "name": "vine whip",
        "type": "grass",
        "base-damage": "7",
        "energy": "6",
        "move-duration-seg": "0.6"
      }
    ]
  }
];

// Recorriendo el JSON con bucles for anidados
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const pokemon = data[i];
  console.log(`Pokémon #${pokemon.num}: ${pokemon.name}`);
  console.log(`Generation: ${pokemon.generation.name}`);
  console.log(`About: ${pokemon.about}`);
  console.log(`Image URL: ${pokemon.img}`);
  console.log(`Height: ${pokemon.size.height}`);
  console.log(`Weight: ${pokemon.size.weight}`);
  console.log(`Rarity: ${pokemon["pokemon-rarity"]}`);
  console.log(`Types: ${pokemon.type.join(", ")}`);
  console.log(`Base Flee Rate: ${pokemon.encounter["base-flee-rate"]}`);
  console.log(`Base Capture Rate: ${pokemon.encounter["base-capture-rate"]}`);
  console.log(`Spawn Chance: ${pokemon["spawn-chance"]}`);
  console.log(`Base Attack: ${pokemon.stats["base-attack"]}`);
  console.log(`Base Defense: ${pokemon.stats["base-defense"]}`);
  console.log(`Base Stamina: ${pokemon.stats["base-stamina"]}`);
  console.log(`Max CP: ${pokemon.stats["max-cp"]}`);
  console.log(`Max HP: ${pokemon.stats["max-hp"]}`);
  console.log(`Resistant: ${pokemon.resistant.join(", ")}`);
  console.log(`Weaknesses: ${pokemon.weaknesses.join(", ")}`);

  // Recorriendo el array de quick moves
  for (let j = 0; j < pokemon["quick-move"].length; j++) {
    const quickMove = pokemon["quick-move"][j];
    console.log(`Quick Move ${j + 1}: ${quickMove.name}`);
    console.log(`Type: ${quickMove.type}`);
    console.log(`Base Damage: ${quickMove["base-damage"]}`);
    console.log(`Energy: ${quickMove.energy}`);
    console.log(`Move Duration: ${quickMove["move-duration-seg"]} seconds`);
  }

  console.log("\n");
}
```

Comment: Por favor, deja de usar ChatGPT. Lee la [política](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) sobre el uso de ChatGPT

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], recuerda dar credito correspondiente para evitar "plagio".